# Changing the orientation of polar chart (From clockwise to anticlockwise)

Tags: vb.net, plot, charts, orientation

I have a code that could plot multiple polar chart series with *Magnitude (in value) **vs** Phase (in degree)*. The provided code is shortened to plot a single series, **S(1,1)**.

```
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Minimum = 0                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Maximum = 360                                  
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Interval = 45                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Crossing = 90    'To change the X axis starting point                                 
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisX.Title = "Magnitude in value"                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Minimum = 0                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Maximum = 1.2                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Interval = 0.2                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "{0:0.#}"                                        
Chart1.ChartAreas("ChartArea1").AxisY.Title = "Phase in degree"
Chart1.Series.Add("S(1,1)")
Chart1.Series("S(1,1)").BorderWidth = 2
Chart1.Series("S(1,1)").Points.DataBindXY(para1, para2)    'para1 is a Double array containing the phase in degree and para2 is a Double array containing the Magnitude in value
Chart1.Series("S(1,1)").ChartType = DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Polar
```

It works fine. However, the orientation of the plot is in clockwise direction, as shown below.

[image: Clockwise Polar plot/Normal Polar plot]

I was trying to change the orientation of this plot to anticlockwise direction with 90 degrees on the top and 270 degrees on the bottom. All I could do is change the X-axis starting point. I checked in a forum on [how to change the orientation of the plot](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/644cb066-3501-417e-8610-6e3340fe6a95/how-to-change-polar-chart-orientation?forum=MSWinWebChart), but it only mentions on how to change the phase values to **360 - original value** and change the X axis labels. That does not help in my case, as I wanted to check datapoints by adding markers and it would show wrong values.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Is the [AxisX.IsReversed Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis.isreversed(v=vs.110).aspx) of any use?

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I have already tried that and it doesn't help to change the orientation of the plot. It only changes the orientation of the X-axis label position from left to right.